# Why is my Crucial m4 SSD Harddrive so slow on an Asrock SATAIII 6GB/s Controller?

Tags: ssd, sata

I bought a new SSD, the Crucial 128GB m4. According to [AS SSD Benchmark](http://www.alex-is.de/PHP/fusion/downloads.php?cat_id=4&download_id=9) it can have 415 MB/s read and about 175 MB/s write.

I have an Asrock X58 Extreme Mainboard with 6 onboard SATAII connectors. So I thought I need a SATAIII Controller, so I bought and [Asrock SATAIII PCIe Controller](http://www.asrock.com/mb/spec/card.asp?Model=SATA3%20Card).

Now the speed on the SATAIII is much too slow, 150 MB/s read, 105 MB/s write. I've installed the latest drivers from Asrock.

When I plug the SSD into the on board SATAII Controller I have 360 MB/s read and 175 MB/s write speed.

What is wrong with it? Why is it not performing as it should?

Comment: What speed is the PCIe slot you've plugged into?

Comment: It's an Asrock X58 Extreme, in the specs it says "PCI Express x1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your PCI Express slot is the bottleneck, especially if it's a `x1`, which means one lane. Your newer slots have 16 lanes, and I'll bet that on those faster slots, the drive would work faster too.

Comment: I plugged it into the x16 one, but it was still slower than the native SATAII Controller, pretty frustrating those slow Intel PCIe lanes.

Comment: It's an x1 card.